# Geofence Transition onHandleIntent is background but Oreo will allow it?

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

With Oreo, when handling geofence transition event in onHandleIntent() are we required to start immediately a Foreground service or can we handle needed work inside onHandleIntent() function (which my understanding runs in the background but should not be allowed in Oreo):

```java
public class GeofenceTransitionsIntentService extends IntentService {
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
      //Do work here...
    }
}
```

vs.

```
public class GeofenceTransitionsIntentService extends IntentService {
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Intent startIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundServices.class);
        this.startForegroundService(startIntent); //and do needed work 
        //inside the Foreground service
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think Android Oreo won´t allow it, I just checked, so I guess we have to do a workaround like the one you mentioned, another thing I am thinking about is launching a broadcast receiver, I am not sure enough though

Answer (score 0):

Use a *JobIntentService* instead (in Kotlin):

```
class GeofenceTransitionsIntentService : JobIntentService() {
    override fun onHandleWork(intent: Intent) {
        val geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent)
        // ...
    }
}
```